# Contact form 7 with wp mail smtp

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I have contact form 7 installed and i want emails to be sent using gmail SMTP.

Im using WP-Mail-SMTP plugin for that matter [WP-mail SMTP](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/)
Is it possible to connect the two plugins to work together ?
Is there another option to do so ?

Comment: http://www.librethinking.com/2013/08/how-to-send-email-in-wordpress-with.html

Answer (score 12):

Contact Form 7 does use the Wordpress settings. If you configure WP-Mail-SMTP and check the radiobutton for "Send all WordPress emails via SMTP.", it will automatically use this settings.

Comment: Remember to test WP-Mail-SMTP after the setting test. It's realy usefull test with a lot of information to debug this process. [Here](https://s.w.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/screenshot-1.png?r=1094851) an image of the WP-Mail-SMTP settings page

Comment: Where can I find the radio button "Send all WordPress emails via SMTP."

Comment: this answer is not useful once it doesn't specify where to findo the radio button

Answer (score 5):

For people who are still facing this issue.

Edit your `Contact Form` and check `From` field under `Mail` tab, and make sure it is same as defined in `WP Mail SMTP > General > From Email`.

Comment: It will still say there's a configuration error as before, but you can safely ignore that and when you try it out it should work - it did for me.